# Is there any library that will generate a tuple and a reconstruction string for JSON data?

Tags: javascript, python, json

I want to ask if there is a library that splits "columns" and "the data" of a JSON string.

Goal:

I need to decrease the amount of data to be transmitted in a telemetry system we have developed.

Under the hood, stringified json data is exchanged. If I were able to divide "columns" and the "data" into separate parts, I would exchange "columns" only once, then the "data" would take much less bandwidth:

```
orig_data = {"hello": 1, "how_are_you": "good"}
template = "{\"hello\": %d, \"how_are_you\": \"%s\"}"
data = (1, "good")

reconstructed_data = json.loads(template % data)
```

`template` will be exchanged only once, then `data` will be sent more efficiently.

A more efficient example would be shown in a digital input/output exchange:

```
orig_data = {"heater_1_started": True, "heater_2_started": False, ..., "heater_76_started": False, "motor_1_running": False, ...}
```

would become

```
data = [0x0345]
```

So, is there any library that will take JSON data and generate the `template` from that information?

## Edit

In the end, I want to have an adaptive protocol:

```
protocol_signature = crc32(template)
if protocol_signature not in synchronized_protocol_signatures: 
    send({'protocol': [protocol_signature, template]})
send([protocol_signature, data])
```

Comment: Do you have to use Json? Google solved this kind of problem with Protocol Buffers (minimizing data transfer with templates, binary encoded, Python supported) https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/

Comment: Protocol Buffer project is exactly what I needed to achieve, but they say they are in beta stage (even though it's in v3.x.x stage...). Moreover, I need to consider backwards compatibility of our current system.

Answer (score 1):

If the fields are always sent in the same order, you could use [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).  Create a `namedtuple` with your column names and then just send over the data values and instantiate a copy of your `namedtuple` class.

```
from collections import namedtuple
import json

# Initial column names (send only once)
column_names = ['x', 'y', 'z']

MyData = namedtuple('MyData', column_names)

json_string_from_server = '[True, 1, "good"]'
json_data = json.loads(json_string_from_server)

data = MyData(*json_data)

print data.x, data.y, data.z
# True 1 "good"
```

As far as compressing the data being sent, it depends on the type of data you're sending.  If it's mostly arbitrary length strings and integers, the stringified json is probably already about as compressed as you can get.

If it's mostly on/off boolean flags that you want to compress into single bits, you can use a library like [bitarray](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/).

```
>>> from bitarray import bitarray
>>> a = bitarray()            # create empty bitarray
>>> a.append(True)
>>> a.extend([False, True, True])
>>> a
bitarray('1011')
```